# How to get a list of dtypes from a numpy structured array?

Tags: numpy, structured-array

How can I get a list of dtypes from a numpy structured array?

**Create example structured array:**

```
arr = np.array([[1.0, 2.0],[3.0, 4.0]])

dt = {'names':['ID', 'Ring'], 'formats':[np.double, np.double]}
arr.dtype = dt
```

```
>>> arr
array([[(1., 2.)],
       [(3., 4.)]], dtype=[('ID', '<f8'), ('Ring', '<f8')])
```

On one hand, it's easy to isolate the column names.

```
>>> arr.dtype.names
('ID', 'RING')
```

However, ironically, none of the `dtype` attributes seem to reveal the individual dtypes.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html lists the attributes of a `dtype` object.

Comment: Yes, I had already tried each attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered that, despite not having dictionary methods like `.items()`, you can still call `dtype['<column_name>']`.

```
column_names = list(arr.dtype.names)
dtypes = [str(arr.dtype[n]) for n in column_names]
```

```
>>> dtypes

['float64', 'float64']
```

Comment: `dtype.fields` is a dict, with name as key, and (dtype, offset) as value.

Comment: `arr.dtype.names` did the job for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or, as @hpaulj hinted, in one step:

```
>>> [str(v[0]) for v in arr.dtype.fields.values()]

['float64', 'float64']
```